# Third-party code blocked the main thread - Defer and Async don't solve it

Tags: javascript, frontend, lighthouse

I'm trying to improve the performance of a website that uses third party JS (as they all do :) ).

After running the Lighthouse analysis the report says:

> Reduce the impact of third-party code Third-party code blocked the main thread

Since every JS blocks the critical path by downloading, parsing and executing the script I pushed all non-critical JS to the bottom of the page and added the *defer* attribute

Nevertheless, I still see the particular JS resource as the blocking the main thread.

Defering the resource should download it in parallel and execute it once the rendering has finished so I really don't get why Lighthouse keeps showing it in the list of main thread blocking resources. Sure, it gets parsed and executed on the main thread, but it's not blocking the critical path and it shouldn't affect the UX that much

What is the best solution to add, for example, Tidio chat widget to the web page without affecting the lighthouse performance score?

Cheers

**EDIT**

I've tested and both defer and async block the main thread

The following code also blocks it

```
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    var tidioScript = document.createElement("script");
    tidioScript.src = "//code.tidio.co/xxxx.js";
    document.body.appendChild(tidioScript);
  });
```

What works is explicitly delaying the injection of the script tag into the DOM:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var tidioScript = document.createElement("script");
    tidioScript.src = "//code.tidio.co/#{tidio_id}.js";
    document.body.appendChild(tidioScript);
  }, 3 * 1000);
```

but this simply feels wrong :/ I thought defer was suppose to achieve the same result :/

Answer (score 3):

I advise you against modifying any of your code so as to accommodate 3rd party scripts.

On the contrary, it is the 3rd party scripts that should accommodate themselves around yours!

So to take full control of the timing of the loading of 3rd party scripts, don’t load them via HTML like this...

```
<script src="https://someplace.com/ThirdParty.js" async>
```

but rather via JS with a time delay of your choice, like this...

```
setTimeout(function(){

 let S=document.createElement('script'); S.type='text/javascript';

 S.src='https://someplace.com/ThirdParty.js';

 try{document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0].appendChild(S);} catch(e){alert(e);}

},3000);
```

Also, try to keep local copies of any 3rd party scripts you are allowed to, so as to avoid the loading/timing dilemma whenever possible.

Comment: I just added an EDIT with a similar solution, but it feels wrong using this when there is "defer" attribute that in my opinion would be the same saying "Parse and execute once everything is rendered"

Comment: defer and async, let the browser make all decisions for you but they're not necessarily always correct, especially as your website gets more and more complex! Sometimes you gotta take control yourself.